# Proper way to deal with unique constraint exception

Tags: core-data, swift3, unique

So I'm downloading a JSON dataset from a webservice and storing them in core data after parsing. One of the entities has unique constraint set, as I don't want redundunct data in the entity. This causes "NSConstraintConflict" exception to be thrown whenever an entry value is already existed in the Core Data. Right now, I'm not handling this exception and let it be thrown. Is it a proper way to handle this situation or is there a better way?

Comment: Ever find an answer?

Comment: Not an ideal way of solving the problem but I used dictionary to keep track of value I've inserted into core data. If dictionary entry is defined, I just skip that value.

Comment: No that's really not an ideal way of handling this, as there's no point on even defining constraints at that point.